# Partial trace of a system with isolated evolution

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-mechanics

Let $\rho_{AB}$ be the state of a composite quantum system with state space $H_A\otimes H_B$ (two finite dimensional Hilbert spaces). Now assume that $A$ and $B$ are isolated and suffer a unitary evolution given by $U_A$ and $U_B$. If we measure the system $A$ then the probability of observing $x$, one of the eigenvalues of the meassurement operator is:

\begin{equation}
P(x)=tr((Pr_x\otimes I)(U_A\otimes U_B)\rho_{AB}(U_A^*\otimes U_B^*))
\end{equation}
where $Pr_x$ is the projector on the eigenspace associated with $x$ and $I$ the identity on $H_B$.

I would like to prove that $P(x)$ is independent of the evolution of system $B$ and in particular follows:
\begin{equation}
P(x)=tr_A(Pr_xU_Atr_B(\rho_{AB})U_A^*)
\end{equation}
where $tr_A$ and $tr_B$ are the partial traces on systems $A$ and $B$. It is not exactly homework, it is just an unproven statement in a textbook.

Comment: Please let us know your definition of composite quantum system. Please don't give orders (as in "Prove...").

Comment: Just changed it, it is just a common statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\def\tr{\operatorname{tr}}
P(x)
&=
\tr((Pr_x\otimes I)(U_A\otimes U_B)\rho_{AB}(U_A^*\otimes U_B^*))
\\
&=
\tr_A(\tr_B((Pr_x\otimes I)(U_A\otimes U_B)\rho_{AB}(U_A^*\otimes U_B^*)))
\\
&=
\tr_A(Pr_x\tr_B((U_A\otimes U_B)\rho_{AB}(U_A^*\otimes U_B^*)))
\\
&=
\tr_A(Pr_x\tr_B((U_A\otimes I)\rho_{AB}(U_A^*\otimes I)))
\\
&=
\tr_A(Pr_xU_A\tr_B(\rho_{AB})U_A^*)\;.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why is it in the fourth equality that $tr_B((U_A\otimes U_B)\rho_{AB}(U_A^*\otimes U_B^*))=tr_B((U_A\otimes I)\rho_{AB}(U_A^*\otimes I))$?

Comment: @Euclean: This is because the trace is invariant with respect to cyclic permutation, and $U_B^*U_B=I$. If you write it out with indices, this is

$$\sum_{\alpha\beta ijkl}U_{A,\alpha i}U_{B,\beta j}\rho_{AB,ijkl}U^*_{A,k\alpha}U^*_{B,l\beta}=\sum_{\alpha ik}U_{A,\alpha i}\left(\sum_m\rho_{AB,imkm}\right)U^*_{A,k\alpha}\;,$$

since $\sum_\beta U_{B,\beta j}U^*_{B,l\beta}=\delta_{jl}$.

Comment: I see, thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Euclean: You're welcome!

Comment: @joriki I'm sure you are correct, but there's twist worth explaining.  $U_B$ can only be cycled that way because it operates only on the subspace being traced over.  A general operator would only cycle under the total trace.